# Android Trading Card Game card objects

Tags: xml, android

I'm writing the GUI for an Android app that plays a trading card game. I have code for a battlefield layout using several views. I need to make an object that represents the deck, and also an object to represent a card in your hand/on the battlefield. The cards, when long-tapped need to bring up a menu of options (attack, defend, etc), or when double tapped in the hand area (green) need to move to the battlefield (blue). I'm not sure what kind of xml object I can use to do this, since it needs to happen dynamically and get data from the back-end code (card name, image). For now I'm just trying to create the objects to appear as black rectangle placeholders before it is incorporated with the game code. Does anybody have any suggestions as to where to start?

Here is the current code for the battlefield layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:background="@color/blue_default">

<View
    android:id="@+id/hand"
    android:background="@color/green_default"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 />

<View
    android:id="@+id/sidebar"
    android:background="@color/gray_default"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/graveyard"
    android:background="@color/red_default"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sidebar"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

Here is an example of what I would like it to look like:

[image]

Comment: Good for you.  Did you have a question?

Comment: The question is how do I go about making such an object?

Comment: @Netsuki, if you are not comfortable writing an XML layout, checkout [AbLE](http://phil-brown.github.io/AbLE/) - it lets you write your layout using simple, annotated java class files - and you can manage all your click hookups in the code.

Comment: @Phil It's not that I'm not comfortable writing in xml, it's that I don't really know what kind of object to use. If each card were to be a button, perhaps that would work. If the deck button is clicked, another button representing the card would be created in the hand area. That button would then need both an onclicklistener and a longclicklistener, so that it can do multiple things. Is there a way to do this for dynamically created buttons? Is there a way to control where on the layout (in which view) the button appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to create a simpler App with plain static stuff arranged as in your mock, I would suggest you to take a look at GridView (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), you could use this component for the Sidebar, Hand and Graveyard sections. Then, you would have to create custom views to populate their Adapters (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews) with single cards, card stacks, buttons, etc...

Remember that the deepest your View Hierarchy goes (the more cards you show and stack on the respective GridViews), the more memory your App will use and Android could close your App if the available memory is eaten.

IMHO, if you are going to create a Game, and because these days games must have a nice and fluid UI with 2D or 3D graphics, you should take advantage of Android's OpenGL support (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html), and create memory efficient objects to handle your game's logic.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm implementing the battlefield with GridView, as you suggested, but I can't seem to find a way to dynamically add an item (card represented by a button) to the grid at runtime. I want to be able to click a "card" in the hand area which will generate a "card" on the battlefield. It would also need to pass a string (the card name, which would be the button's text) but I cannot even figure out generating a button in the first place.

Comment: Populate the GridView with a SimpleCursorAdapter connected to your Model or make your own custom Adapter extending BaseAdapter and populate it manually. You can insert views on a GridView's Adapter dynamically, refresh it at will, etc. GridView will display anything that extends from android.view.View, such Button, TextView, etc. Put only the game elements such as cards and stacks on the GridView,  create your custom views to represent them. The buttons, well... because they are static, they could be just a button next to the GridView so you don't have to re-insert them again and again.

Comment: I have a custom Adapter called ButtonAdapter. It currently generates the battlefield cards (buttons) from a non-dynamic array of strings as a test. I chose buttons to act as cards for convenience, as the cards need to have multiple listeners (onclick, long press, etc). What I would like to happen is for a button/card to be added to the battlefield grid when a button representing the deck is clicked in the sidebar. Is there a way for a button in the sidebar view to generate a new grid item in the battlefield GridView (and pass it a string)?

Comment: Read more about Adapters (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) for the GridView's views. That is the key. Oh... and you can use the View's tag to transfer the String (or a POJO) you want to pass when the click happens. Good luck man!

Answer (score 0):

Standard Android XML Layouts are very convenient when it's about building a business UI with static views (not moving or changing position), but I'm not sure that that's the best choice for such a board game.

I guess that cards will have to move (animation from deck to board position), or that special effects could be added.

In that case, I'd go to a more dynamic screen, using a 2D engine like AndEngine or Cocos2D for instance.
If you're not afraid to dive into some 2D framework, they will give you a lot of flexibility and possibilities.